# Angular2 Merging observables

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs

I'm having trouble getting with some observables. I can't seem to get two
observables to place nice together. They work just fine on their own, but I
need both values.

```js
db.glass.subscribe( ( glass: GlassData[] ): void => {
  console.log( glass ); // This prints
});

db.cassette_designs.subscribe( ( cassettes: CassetteData[] ): void => {
  console.log( cassettes ): // This prints
});
```

Not being all that familiar with observables, the first thing I tried was
nesting one inside the other, but the inner one doesn't seem to do anything.

```js
db.glass.subscribe( ( glass: GlassData[] ): void => {
  console.log( glass ); // This prints

  db.cassette_designs.subscribe( ( cassettes: CassetteData[] ): void => {
    console.log( cassettes ): // This doesn't
  });
});
```

This seemed a bit silly to be so I searched on Google to see if there was a
better way to combine observables and it turns out there are a few. I tried
`zip` and `forkJoin` since they looked the most like what I wanted to do, but
nothing would work with them either.

```js
Observable.zip( db.cassette_designs, db.glass, ( cassettes: CassetteData[], glass: GlassData[] ): void => {
  console.log( cassettes ); // doesn't print
  console.log( glass     ); // doesn't print
});

Observable.forkJoin( [ db.cassette_designs, db.glass ] ).subscribe( ( data: any ): void => {
  console.log( data ); // doesn't print
});
```

It could be something as simple as I'm not calling the functions correctly, but
I'd have thought I would get some sort of warning or error at some point. `tsc`
doesn't have any problem with the code and I get no messages in the developer
consoles on either Chrome or Firefox.

## Update

I've tried `combineLatest`, but it still doesn't display anything in the console. I must be missing something, but I'm not sure what. They work individually.

```js
Observable.combineLatest( db.cassette_designs, db.glass, ( cassettes: CassetteData[], glass: GlassData[] ): void => {
  console.log( cassettes ); // doesn't print
  console.log( glass     ); // deson't print
});
```

The observables are create in the following way:

```js
...

public Listen( event: string ): Observable<Response>
{
  return new Observable<Response>( ( subscriber: Subscriber<Response> ): Subscription => {
    const listen_func = ( res: Response ): void => subscriber.next( res );

    this._socket.on( event, listen_func );

    return new Subscription( (): void =>
      this._socket.removeListener( event, listen_func ) );
  });
}

...
```

Then to actually get the observables I send a listen for responses on the relevant event. e.g.

```js
...

public cassette_designs: Observable<CassetteData[]>;

...

this.cassette_designs = _socket.Listen( "get_cassette_designs" )
    .map( ( res: Response ) => res.data.data );
```

Comment: SO curious about what your project is! Cassettes and glass and they're all playing together! Love it!

Comment: It was an online tool that allowed users to design doors.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I managed to get `combineLatest` to work, by actually subscribing to the resulting
observable.

Originally I was doing this:

```js
Observable.combineLatest( db.cassette_designs, db.glass, ( cassettes: CassetteData[], glass: GlassData[] ): void => {
  console.log( cassettes );
  console.log( glass     );
});
```

Now I'm doing this:

```js
Observable.combineLatest( db.cassette_designs, db.glass ).subscribe( ( data: any[] ): void => {
  console.log( data );
  // cassettes - data[0]
  // glass     - data[1]
});
```

Answer (score 7):

To follow up with your findings:

1) An `Observable` is a lazy execution data type, this means that it will not execute anything in the pipeline until it is subscribed to. This goes for the combinatorial operators as well. `zip`, `forkJoin`, `combineLatest`, and `withLatestFrom` will all recursively subscribe to the `Observables` that you pass them only *after* they themselves have subscriptions.

Hence:

```
var output = Observable.combinelatest(stream1, stream2, (x, y) => ({x, y}));
```

Won't actually do anything until you call `output.subscribe()`, at which point `subscribe` is also called on `stream1` and `stream2` and you get all the magic of Rx.

2) A more minor point but whenever you start doing your own creation methods, have a look first at the documentation to see if it already exists. There are static creation methods for, `Arrays`, `Promises`, Node-style callbacks and yes even standard [event patterns](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/observable/FromEventObservable.ts).

Thus your `Listen` method can become:

```
public Listen<R>(event: string): Observable<R> {
  return Observable.fromEvent(this._socket, event);
}
```

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. In regards to the way I'm getting observables, the main reason I'm doing it the way I am is to make sure that unsubscribing from the observable also removes the listener. I'll take a look through the documentation and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Hey if you want to have a single stream (observable) that emits a combination data of the 2 sources, check out `combineLatest` method.

Answer (score 1):

Both of them: Observable.zip and Observable.forkJoin must work. (Personally, I prefer 'forkJoin' - it returns an array with the same order, as you pushed observables, and you don't need a plenty of arguments)

Maybe, if you are creating observables manually (Observable.create...), you just forgot to call 'completed' for both provided Observers from 'create' method.

Answer (score 0):

I've used **combineLatest**. I needed three *API* calls, but I wanted only one Object combining the three responses.

I've followed to formula mentioned in this same post:

```
var output = Observable.combinelatest(stream1, stream2, (x, y) => ({x, y}));
```

Being the final code:

```
getGobalStats(): Observable<any> {

    let obs1 = this._http.get(this._config.getGlobalStatsUrl(), this._config.getOptions())
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json().content;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => { console.error(error); return error; });
    let obs2 = this._http.get(this._config.getGlobalStatsUrl() + '?type=1', this._config.getOptions())
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json().content;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => { console.error(error); return error; });
    let obs3 = this._http.get(this._config.getGlobalStatsUrl() + '?type=3', this._config.getOptions())
      .map((res: Response) => {
        return res.json().content;
      })
      .catch((error: any) => { console.error(error); return error; });

      return Observable.combineLatest(obs1,obs2,obs3,(res1,res2,res3) => { return {all:res1,running: res2, cycling: res3}});
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        Observable.merge(
            Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousedown'), Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'touchstart'))
            .switchMap((e) => {
                return Observable.merge(
                    Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mousemove').takeUntil(Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'mouseup')),
                    Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'touchmove').takeUntil(Observable.fromEvent(canvasEl, 'touchend')),
                )
                    .pairwise()
            })
            .subscribe(...
```